# how to get current console background and text colors?

Tags: c++, windows, colors, console

I know how to set them (SetConsoleTextAttribute) but there isn't a GetConsoleTextAttribute to retrieve this information. On a unaffected console it should be int 7.

The problem is that when exiting from a program that sets the text color it stays the same for the time given window runs, and I cannot assume that user hasn't set the colors to his custom liking.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A quick grep of `wincon.h` shows that `CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO` has a `wAttributes` member which is [documented as](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682093%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) "The attributes of the characters written to a screen buffer by the WriteFile and WriteConsole functions, or echoed to a screen buffer by the ReadFile and ReadConsole functions." This matches [the description of `SetConsoleTextAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686047%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): "Sets the attributes of characters written to the console screen buffer by the WriteFile or WriteConsole function, or echoed by the ReadFile or ReadConsole function." The structure is returned by `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo`.

Answer (score 11):

Thanks to Talent25 I made this function:

```
#include <Windows.h>    
bool GetColor(short &ret){
        CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO info;
        if (!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &info))
            return false;
        ret = info.wAttributes;
        return true;
}
```

using it:

```
GetColor(CurrentColor);
```

CurrentColor - variable for output number of color (background * 16 + main color). Returned value informs if action was successful.

Answer (score 8):

Here is code snippet.

```
HANDLE                      m_hConsole;
WORD                        m_currentConsoleAttr;
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO   csbi;

//retrieve and save the current attributes
m_hConsole=GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
if(GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(m_hConsole, &csbi))
    m_currentConsoleAttr = csbi.wAttributes;

//change the attribute to what you like
SetConsoleTextAttribute (
            m_hConsole,
            FOREGROUND_RED |
            FOREGROUND_GREEN);

//set the ttribute to the original one
SetConsoleTextAttribute (
            m_hConsole,
            m_currentConsoleAttr);
```