# How to know console background and text colors?

Tags: colors, console, freepascal

[*** NOT A DUPLICATE ***](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8578909) as it refers to C++ and Windows only.

(Currently for Windows, but a solution also for Linux is preferred.)

I have an application that uses TextColor and/or TextBackground to highlight some text.  Because a user may alter the console defaults, I would like to be able to read those colors so I can adjust the color of my highlights to not blend with the user's colors.

For example, if the user has selected yellow text, I don't want my highlight to also be yellow, or if the user's background is red I don't want the highlight to be red and disappear.

I checked the RTL.PDF and couldn't find anything.  But that manual is really long (2K+ pages), and I may have missed it.

My question: Are there equivalent functions to TextColor and TextBackground that instead of setting the colors, return the currently set values?  (Or, if not specific functions, maybe some other method like getting all console parameters that also contains this color information.)

UPDATE:

After being 'pushed' to deal with C++, and go study the Windows API, I went and did all that :)

Luckily, I found an unrelated FreePascal example of a console Windows API call in the Lazarus forum, and putting all this together, I came up with this which I post as I'm sure it will be useful to others:

```
{$mode fpc}
Unit Console;

Interface

uses Windows, SysUtils;

function GetTextColor: Byte;
function GetTextBackground: Byte;

Implementation

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function GetColors: Byte;
var
  vHandle :THandle;
  vScreenBufInfo :TConsoleScreenBufferInfo;
begin
  vHandle := GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  if vHandle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then RaiseLastOSError;
  GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(vHandle,vScreenBufInfo);
  GetColors := vScreenBufInfo.wAttributes;
end;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function GetTextColor: Byte;
begin
  GetTextColor := GetColors and $0F;
end;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function GetTextBackground: Byte;
begin
  GetTextBackground := GetColors shr 4 and $0F;
end;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

begin
  //Writeln('TextColor      : ',GetTextColor);
  //Writeln('BackgroundColor: ',GetTextBackground);
end.
```

**I'm still looking for a Linux solution, however.  Anyone?**

Comment: Why does the duplicate being in a different language matter? It still tells you how to detect the console background and text colors. The solution is still `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo`on Windows, regardless of the coding language you're using.

Comment: @KenWhite Except that I shouldn't be required to learn C++ to solve a FreePascal related problem, I have already checked the API calls in the FreePascal manual and didn't find equivalents.  So, it's not a case of simple porting from one language to another.  Besides, I'd also like a Linux-compatible solution which that not-duplicate does not mention.

Comment: There isn't an equivalent in FP, because the procedure is not FP. It's a Windows API call, and there are many Delphi translations of it available via Google. If you're going to work with the WinAPI, you need to learn enough C to be able to at least make an effort to do the translations yourself. Both Delphi and FP can easily work with the required types. And yes, in order to work with the WinAPI, you **are** required to learn to at least read C. And any Linux-compatible call will most likely have to be coded separately and handled with a compiler define, as the calls are platform specific.